# SQL Query for combining rows with duplicates

Tags: sql, orientdb

I'm brand new to OrientDb and feeling a bit confused.

I have some data that looks like this:

```
md5hash       sessionId  path
------------------------------------
value0        zzz        roosters
value1        aaa        cows
value1        bbb        ducks
value1        bbb        pigs
value1        ccc        chickens
value1        aaa        horses
value2        ggg        sheep
```

I want everything with the `md5hash` of `value1`, with any repeat paths showing up as children of the parent `md5hash`, so I tried a query like:

`SELECT md5hash, sessionId, path, FROM file WHERE md5hash="value1"`

Here's what I want it to look like:

```
md5hash       sessionId  path
------------------------------------
value1        aaa        cows
                         horses
value1        bbb        ducks
                         pigs
value1        ccc        chickens
```

Or even better, to look like this:

```
md5hash       sessionId  path
------------------------------------
value1        aaa        cows, horses
value1        bbb        ducks, pigs
value1        ccc        chickens
```

But any time I add a `GROUP BY` clause, it eliminates data. If I group by `sessionId`, then I loose `horses` and `pigs`.

I've also monkied with `DISTINCT` to no avail. I feel like I'm missing something very basic here.

This is what it ends up looking like with my query:

```
md5hash       sessionId  path
-------------------------------
value1        aaa        cows
value1        aaa        horses
value1        bbb        ducks
value1        bbb        pigs
value1        ccc        chickens
```

Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `GROUP_CONCAT` aggreagtion function equivalent

Comment: @lad2025 I can't seem to find a `GROUP_CONCAT` for OrientDb. It looks like it would do the exact right thing though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
select md5hash, sessionId, $a.path from (select from file where md5hash="value1")
let $a=(select from file where md5hash="value1" and sessionId=$parent.current.sessionId)
group by sessionId
```

This is the output:

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards

Comment: Wow. That totally works. Can you add more detail to explain how the multiple `SELECT` queries work (the `LET` line is what I'm not understanding)? I don't see how it ends up with a comma-delimited list of the paths. Thanks!

Comment: I try to explain it :

1) with select from file where md5hash="value1" you select only the records that have the property "md5hash" set to "value1".

2) with this let $a=(select from file where md5hash="value1" and sessionId=$parent.current.sessionId): you select the record that have md5hash="value1" and sessionId equal to the parent record (the ones you made in step 1).

3) gruop by sessionId.

4) select md5hash, sessionId, $a.path
   it select the fields md5hash, sessionId and the list of path that have those values of md5hash, sessionId.

Hope it helps.

Comment: @AlessandroRota Thank you very much. I don't understand how it iterates through all the potential hits, but it obviously does. Would it be accurate to say that for each result it finds in Step 1, it does a Step 2 query? Also, why `select from file` again, instead of `select from $parent` in step 2? Thanks. :-)

Comment: @kmort Say that for each result it finds in Step 1, it does a Step 2 is correct. I tried with select from $parent but it didn't work.